# Angular 1.x unable to add class to custom directive based on internal logic

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `ng-repeat` directive that renders some elements. I've added a custom directive to each element to add additional functionality. Based on internal directive logic (if `a` is greater than `b` for that matter) I want to add a class to that directive. So far I've not been able to achieve this goal.

JS:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      myDirective: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        /*internal logic*/
    if(a > b){
        //add class to the current directive
        //something like this.addClass("redText");
    }
    }
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="pos in positions" my-directive="pos">

</div>
```

Comment: element.addClass("redText");

Comment: Thanks! cant believe it was so easy.. and my guess was so close. Post this as an answer and i'll accept it

Comment: Added anwser, so others can refer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `element` to do DOM manipulation.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      myDirective: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        /*internal logic*/
    if(a > b){
        element.addClass("redText");
    }
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: You copied my answer DUDE really!!

Comment: He answered it first as a comment to my post.

Comment: @ashishyadav Not really my friend. Copied from question.